# Multiple actions with dependencies in Redux-Observable

Tags: javascript, react-redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am using Redux-Observable Epic in a React & Redux project. I have multiple actions need to emit, originally this is what I have been doing,

1) Catch the START_ACTION in the Epic
2) Fetch remote data
3) Return a new Observanble

for example:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operator/mergeMap';


const fetchAsync = (arg) => {
   // return an observable of promise
   return Observable::from(fetch(url + arg));
} 

export function myEpic = (action$) => {
   action$.ofType(START_ACTION)
    ::switchMap(action => {
       return fetchAsync('/action.payload')
          ::mergeMap(result => {
             return Observable::of({type: ACTION_COMPLETE, payload: result})
          }) 
    })
 };
```

Now what if I have another action `SECOND_ACTION` need to be emitted after the `START_ACTION` and before the `ACTION_COMPLETE` ? In other word, without making sure the `SECOND_ACTION` hits the reducer, the `ACTION_COMPLETE` should not be emitted.

I could write another separate Epic function to do this, but is there any other easier way?

Comment: What should happen to the `ACTION_COMPLETE` action while it waits for the `SECOND_ACTION`? What if it never comes?

Comment: Or do you mean you want this epic to emit `SECOND_ACTION` then immediately followed by the `ACTION_COMPLETE`? i.e. emit two actions

Comment: I want to emit `FIRST_ACTION` then immediately followed by `SECOND_ACTION`. I am thinking about using `dispatch(SECOND_ACTION)` in the action function which return `FIRST_ACTION`

Comment: Where is `FIRST_ACTION` coming from? It's not in your question above. did you maybe mean `ACTION_COMPLETE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To simplify the question, I just want to emit the SECOND_ACTION before the async.

To emit another action before performing the `fetchAsync`, you can either use `Observable.concat` or the `startWith` operator, which is basically sugar for the concat.

```
export function myEpic = (action$) => {
   action$.ofType(START_ACTION)
    ::switchMap(action => {
       return fetchAsync('/action.payload')
          ::map(result => ({ type: ACTION_COMPLETE, payload: result })
          ::startWith({ type: SECOND_ACTION })
    })
 };
```

Since `SECOND_ACTION` synchronously follows `START_ACTION`, keep in mind that often you should just have your reducers listen for `START_ACTION` instead of emitting another action. Multiple reducers transitions state from the same action is normal and one of the primary benefits of redux.

That said, there are certainly some times where the separation of concerns is more ideal, so this is more of a general tip.

---

### Previous answer

If you want to emit two actions sequentially you can pass the additional actions as arguments to `Observable.of(...actions)` since it accepts any number of arguments and emits them sequentially.

```
export function myEpic = (action$) => {
   action$.ofType(START_ACTION)
    ::switchMap(action => {
       return fetchAsync('/action.payload')
          ::mergeMap(result => {
             return Observable::of(
               { type: SECOND_ACTION },
               { type: ACTION_COMPLETE, payload: result }
             )
          }) 
    })
 };
```

If this isn't what you meant, I apologize. The question isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apologize for unclear question. The `FIRST_ACTION` comes from action file, triggered by the user. For example, you can imagine it as a action caused by clicking `submit` button in the form. This will emit an action to the reducer to update the `state` saying that "Hey, I am submitting something to the database (asynchronously)". React will display a loading spinner according to the state change.

Comment: To simplify the question, I just want to emit the `SECOND_ACTION` before the async.